# What is the best Facebook / Twitter SSO framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, single-sign-on

I have a website where I want users to be able to leave reviews and rate products.  I want some sort of SSO based system where they can use existing facebook / twitter accounts to "sign in".  It is essential that I am able to uniquely identify them once they have so that they cannot rate products more than once etc.

What is the best system to use?

The requirements are:

1. Easy to implement
2. Lightweight
3. Facebook / Twitter integration
4. Ability to uniquely identify users
   once they are signed on and possibly retrieve basic information such as First name and initial etc

Comment: I am really tempted to down-vote just because this title is absolutely horrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like [Janrain Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage) which is a library that lets you integrate login with popular social media sites.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at Wordpress, it is, in my opinion, one of the better frameworks for this sort of thing. There's a plugin called WP-FB AutoConnect here:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-fb-autoconnect/

Hope this helps

Comment: I'd also say wordpress in this case, with said plugin. Or if you want it to be more community-like, buddypress.

Comment: Unfortunately the site cannot use wordpress as its totally bespoke

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing that comes close is [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

Comment: How would you use that for SSO?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your skill level is, but if you don't want something like wordpress. I've used CodeIgniter with https://github.com/ericbae/Tank-Auth---3rd-Party-Authentication-Project

It gives you facebook, twitter and google friend connect.